# PDO MySQL "not in()" not working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a query that returns related video titles from a given video so same genre, country, date published etc.

I want to exclude certain `video_names` using `not in ()` function. The problem is that the query returns the videos I want to exclude and they are sorted first in the array also. Why is this happening?

```
public function interval($month, $not, $limit) {
    $this->not = array_unique($not);
    $i = implode(',', $this->not);

    echo $i;//prints: onajr,babyjem,posh

    $query = '
        select title, artists, published, views, video_name, yt_id, duration, play_start, genre, country from videos
        where
        published BETWEEN :published - INTERVAL :month MONTH AND :published + INTERVAL :month MONTH
        and MATCH(country) AGAINST(:country IN boolean mode)
        and MATCH(genre) AGAINST(:genre IN boolean mode)
        and
        video_name not in (" :i ")
        ORDER BY RAND() limit :limit
    ';

    $run_query = $this->pdo->prepare($query);

    $run_query->bindValue(':published', $this->published);
    $run_query->bindValue(':country', '+' . $this->data->country);
    $run_query->bindValue(':genre', '+' . $this->data->genre);
    $run_query->bindValue(':limit', $limit, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $run_query->bindValue(':month', $month, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $run_query->bindValue(':i', $i);

    $run_query->execute();
    $data =  $run_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    print_r($data);
    //contains all three of them onajr,babyjem,posh
}
```

Comment: `video_name not in ( :i )`

Comment: Going to add @ MichaelBerkowski comment here, "PDO isn't going to expand a comma-separated list into an `IN ()` list, it's going to treat it as a single string value to `IN ()` which happens to include literal `,`" You will need to dynamically build `$i` and the binding; 1 value per placeholder.

Comment: so bind each `video_name` separately? @AlonEitan comment is working fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create array of the parameters and the values like this:

```
$this->not = array_unique($not);
$i = array();
foreach( $this->not as $key => $val ) {
    $i[':vid_' . $key] = $val;
}
```

Bind it to the query:

```
' ..... video_name not in ('. implode(',', array_keys($i)) .') ....'
```

And then, bind the params:

```
foreach( $i as $key => $val ) {
    $run_query->bindValue($key, $val);
}
```

Comment: `video_name not in ( :i )` is working fine and the excluded videos ore not being shown.

Comment: Oh, that's good to know. Still - My answer maybe useful when you'd want to bind strings and not only numbers

Comment: yes but its working fine. I'm testing and those videos are not shown. anyway thanks.